# How to fix getaddrinfo-failure for python on windows

Tags: python, windows, getaddrinfo

if a start python in a command prompt terminal and try to open some url, I get the following result, despite the name being resolveable through DNS:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup www.google.de
Nicht-autorisierende Antwort:
Name:    www-cctld.l.google.com
Address:  173.194.69.94
Aliases:  www.google.de
C:\Windows\system32>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.de")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 84, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 205, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 342, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 754, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
>>>
```

I disabled the firewall, started the command prompt as Administrator, but that’s pretty much all I can think of. nslookup works just fine, so I don't see what’s wrong.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently within Internet Explorer connection settings, an unreachable proxy was defined and for whatever reason urllib considers this setting and thus caused the error.

Comment: It's worth noting, for those of us not used to the ways of Microsoft, that Internet Explorer settings can affect other programs as well. Proxy settings, at least in Windows Server 2012, are buried under Internet Explorer → ⚙ → Tools → Internet Options → Connections → LAN Settings. (And before any of you Appleheads start crowing, at least those steps are labelled with characters, and not pretty-coloured knobs that apparently have meaning in the Mac World.)