# Cannot fetch URLs from GAE local environment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2

I'm getting the following error when trying to fetch an URL with urllib2 in the google app engine:

```
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://www.google.com Error: [Errno 10106] getaddrinfo failed
```

This is the code calling the urllib2 open read methods:

```
def get(self):
        self.write(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read())
        self.render_index()
```

Nothing fancy, just a call to the library inside the main handler to ouptut the fetched text.

My PC resolves DNS correctly. I can use the urllib2 library from the python interpeter, fetching URLs successfully.

The deployed code running from the google servers work as intended, it's something with my local environment but I can't find what is it.

I also tried using urlfetch from gae with similar results (same getaddrinfo failed)

I switched to Google DNS some days before working with the urllib2 library but switching back to ISP provided DNS didn't work either.

EDIT: When calling the function with an IP address the URL is fetched:

```
self.write(urllib2.urlopen("http://173.194.42.34").read())
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain that your DNS resolver fails to resolve the hostname. I assume that your OS, or security software prohibits the devserver from creating outbound connection. Another possibility would be that you have invalid entry in your hosts file on your operating system.

Also, there are [many similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-app-engine%5D%20getaddrinfo%20failed) which could help you.

Comment: I did look at least three times at each of the questions with the "getaddrinfo failed" code but they only helped me troubleshoot and discard possible problems.
Hosts content: 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: Tried switching windows firewall and antivirus off but the behavior is still the same.

Comment: How about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925903/how-to-fix-getaddrinfo-failure-for-python-on-windows

Comment: No, I haven't got a proxy configured in any of my browsers. Could it be an ISP issue?

Comment: Please determine it by invoking the following command in the command line:
> ping www.google.com

Comment: `C:\Users\Developer>ping www.google.com
Pinging www.google.com [173.194.42.51] with 32 bytes of data:`

The address is resolving, as it does on my browser and on the python interpreter.

With ISP issue I meant some proxy I can't determine if present or not (i think they are called transparent) that prevents the app from connecting.

Comment: I tried the same program on my brothers laptop with the same results. We are going out through the same router->modem