# Python 2.7.10 Win7(64-bit) OS URLError

Tags: python, dns, urllib2

I tried to run the code below with Python 2.7.10 Shell:

```
# encoding: utf8
import urllib2
import re
response=urllib2.urlopen("https://www.baidu.com/")
print response.read()
```

Unfortunately, I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vivid\Desktop\LISA\datacrawling\ex.py", line 6, in <module>
    response=urllib2.urlopen("https://www.baidu.com/")
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python2710\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Do you have any ideas about the problem? I've been caught by it for a long time...Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the issue. Its likely to do with your config. `getaddrinfo` is using DNS lookup to determine the ip address of baidu.com and thats what not working. I'd suggest that perhaps you search for other similar questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5022945/urllib2-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11004-getaddrinfo-failed) which may answer your question.

Comment: The DNS lookup failed because of your Internet connection. This has nothing to do with python.

Comment: @PaulRooney Hey Paul, I actually have the same question as the one you  post, but none of answers to it could solve the problem well. Clearly, DNS lookup goes wrong, though Internet connection works well.

Comment: @skyline75489 My Internet connection works well...

Comment: @VitoWong what happens if you do `ping www.baidu.com` from Windows command prompt?

Comment: @PaulRooney `C:\Windows\System32>ping www.baidu.com  

Pinging www.a.shifen.com [61.135.169.121] with 32 bytes of data:  
Reply from 61.135.169.121: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=56  
Reply from 61.135.169.121: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=56  
Reply from 61.135.169.121: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=56  
Reply from 61.135.169.121: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=56  

Ping statistics for 61.135.169.121:  
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),  
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:  
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms`

Comment: That works, so it's likely a config issue. I can't reproduce it so I'm sorry I can't help you. I'd suggest googling the issue and also trying some other urls to see if they have the issue. If you need a short term work around you could use the IP address of baidu in your code. I'm not sure how often it changes.

Comment: Another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925903/how-to-fix-getaddrinfo-failure-for-python-on-windows

Comment: @PaulRooney I've tried many urls even including those without "www", but it still failed to work. I just wanna learn python scrapy and start the simplest code, but...Anyway, it's very nice of you to help me so much. Thank you, Paul!

Comment: Final advice consider using linux. You could install as VM or dual boot. These issues will disappear.