# pip install connection error

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a library called gmplot using pip. This worked fine on my Mac but not my Windows 10 machine. I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Alex>pip install gmplot
Collecting gmplot
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003BD70B8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/gmplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003BD7A58>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/gmplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003BD7DA0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/gmplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003BD75C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/gmplot/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000003BD7D30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/gmplot/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gmplot (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for gmplot
```

Other stackoverflow threads mention adding proxy details in the pip command, but I don't use a proxy. I've also changed my DNS to Google's DNS but this didn't work.

(Python 2.7)

Comment: For fun I tried this and it works. You don't write anything about your internet setup. One way of solving this is to go to some other windows 10 machine with the same python version and type "pip download gmplot". You can move the downloaded files to a directory on your machine and in that "pip install gmplot --no-index --find-links . ". This is how I install pip downloads on machines with no internet...

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what to say about my internet set-up. Just a normal home broadband/wifi connection, no proxy, no VPN, no issues accessing any parts of the internet except in the case above. Unfortunately I don't have another Windows machine but in the worst case I will find one.

Comment: you may also want to upgrade python to a current (3.6.1) version or upgrade pip and then retry...

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925903/how-to-fix-getaddrinfo-failure-for-python-on-windows ; the problem there was a proxy setting.

Comment: Thanks but I don't use a proxy. I checked in my settings that this is the case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proxy awareness with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30992717/proxy-awareness-with-pip)

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was to set the proxy in the .bash_profile in the root directory.  If this file is not there create it.

EX :

export http_proxy=

This was done on a Centos System with connection to the internet on a virtual machine.

Comment: what should the http_proxy variable be set to?

Comment: Yeah, but this is on a virtual machine so it doesn't look like it applies to this problem.